# What is difference between CreateMap() & DynamicMap() function in Auto mapper c#

Tags: c#, automapper

i never use auto mapper but hard many people use it to map two different object.i was reading few code snippet & article that showed how we can use auto mapper to map datatable data to Person entity classes.

i really did not know that auto mapper can be used to populate entity classes from datatable data.

here i got a guide line like

```
using (IDataReader dr = DatabaseContext.ExecuteReader(command))
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, ProductModel>();
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<ProductModel>>(dr);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**http://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/**
i saw few people use `CreateMap() function and few use DynamicMap()`. so i like to know what is the difference between this two function?

when we should use use CreateMap() function & when we should use use DynamicMap() function ?
if possible please explain with example code & situation like when we should use one.

```
public class Person {
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
}


List<Person> people = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Person>>(
    sourceDataTable.CreateDataReader());
```

just we should use DynamicMap() function to write one line less code ? because when we use CreateMap() function when we need to say name of two mapping object but when we use DynamicMap() then in one line we can do all. did i understand properly or the actual things or purpose of DynamicMap() function is different?

another issue is suppose when my entity classes property name is different and data table column name is different then how we can populate my entity class from data table?

suppose if data type is different then how to handle the situation ? data table column type is int but entity class field type is long or double....so how we can cast and store data?

please let me know whatever i asked here with code sample if possible. thanks.

Comment: http://www.softwarerockstar.com/2011/05/complex-object-mapping-using-automapper/   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157601/Working-with-Entities-instead-of-DataTable-Objects

Comment: Please try to use the search and ask one question per question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740362/automapper-why-use-map-over-dynamicmap, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489188/the-differences-between-a-normal-map-with-dynamic-map-automapper, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101516/automapper-how-to-parse-an-int-from-a-string-and-possible-to-creating-rules-bas

Comment: @CodeCaster why is this voted to close? the question is pretty straight and clear. If the OP tried to address more concerns in the body that is ok

Comment: @AZ. because the separate questions _"What is DynamicMap() and when to use it instead of Map()?"_  **and** _"How to map columns of different data types?"_ are answered in the links I provided. Two relatively unrelated questions in one: too broad.

Comment: thanks to all of you :)